# Is it normal to get no retransmissions using TCP on Nordic Boards?

Tags: networking, tcp

For a Projekt I am connecting 2 Nordic Boards together over IEEE 802.15.4 and measure their bandwidth using TCP. The two nrf52840dk Boards are 1m apart (one acting as a border router for my PC).
Streamlength is always 100 and Payload length from 10 Bytes to 1000 Bytes (I even stresstested it with 128KB) (Of course the Boards will split the Payloads by themself into more packets anyway). I am using RIOT os on the boards and a custom benchmark.

**I get 0 retransmissions** after many measurements with different Payload sizes. I am not experianced with this, but read online that it is normal for around 1% retransmissions over the internet and wanted to make sure that this is to be expected for my local case even after many MB of sended data in total.

Comment: So.. you made perfect-world test rig and got perfect-world results?

Comment: @PTwr Since this is my first time doing something like this, I do not know how perfekt results can be :( So yould you say this result can be exspected?

Comment: Perfect result would be no retransmission's, as retransmission's are symptom of a problem, which is being fixed automagically by C in TCP.

Comment: @PTwr I take that as a yes  (I know what they are, but I have only theoretical expercience)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I later found out my results were wrong. The benchmark was broken and not properly measuring retransmissions. It seems to me that no retransmissions are unrealistic for even a few Kilobytes, at least for my case.